# Masonry with full-width items

Tags: javascript, css, masonry

I am having an issue with Masonry where if I need one element to be 100% width and the rest to be 50% width, the layout no longer puts my elements adjacent to each other. What I would like is for the items to show up side-by-side like they do when there is no 100%-width element.

Here's a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ubmf47s4/2/

```
    <div id="boxes" class="masonry clearfix">
    <div class="box box-fw" style="background: cyan;">
        <div class="inner">
        <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background: magenta;">
        <div class="inner">
        <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background: yellow;">
        <div class="inner">
        <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background: grey;">
        <div class="inner">
        <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.box{
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box-fw{
   width:100%
}

    $(function(){
    var container = $('#boxes');

    container.imagesLoaded(function(){  
        //console.log( "Images loaded!" );
        container.masonry({
           itemSelector: '.box',
            isAnimated: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What stops working all together? At 100% of width, there shouldn't be any masonry effect? Could you at least provide the image of the layout that you visioned or have in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Masonry requires a `columnWidth` to determine the width of the columns for it to lay out your content in, which can either be a direct pixel value or a selector for an element to measure. Since `columnWidth` is not specified in your code, Masonry defaults to measuring the first element in your masonry container to establish the column width. Since your first element is the one with 100% width, Masonry measures it and sets your column width to 100%, which is why your 50%-width elements no longer show up side-by-side (your entire masonry layout is effectively a single column).

More about this behavior [in the Masonry docs for columnWidth](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html).

---

One way to fix this is to specify an element that Masonry can measure to establish your column width - in this case I've used an element with the class `column-sizer`, which I've sized at 50% using CSS. Masonry then measures this element to determine the column size for layout. I borrowed the technique from [David Desandro's fluid columnWidth CodePen example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpeg).

**Screenshot of Result:**

[image: Result screenshot]

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var container = $('#boxes');

  container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    //console.log( "Images loaded!" );
    container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: '.column-sizer',
      isAnimated: true
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.box,
.column-sizer {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-fw {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div id="boxes" class="masonry clearfix">
  <div class="column-sizer"></div>
  <div class="box box-fw" style="background: cyan;">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background: magenta;">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background: yellow;">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background: grey;">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>lkaj dlksaj ldksjf lkdj flksd flkds flkds flksd jfakldsjf lkdsj flkjfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/x9mf2c6x/

Comment: Judging from the JS Fiddle seems like it should work.  I got them to change the design up so it's not 100%, but I still wanna try it to see how it looks. Thank u so much!